# A webcomic where the friend of the deceased saintess gets the attention of the male leads?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I lost a manhua/manwha I was reading about the sudden death of the saintess (or something) and then her being survived by her best friend. The best friend was berated by the male leads until the saintess's death and they start to see similarities between the two and approach her more.

Our MC (the best friend) was a plain Jane kind of character with long dark brown or black hair. Pretty sure she was a lower-ranked noble and the parents of the late saintess also took an interest in her after the death of their daughter since she was closest to her. Think the parents were higher-ranked nobles, and the saintess (or something, definitely not crown princess but a jewel of society for some reason: her kindness being primary to that) had platnimum white/blue or blonde hair. The two were always compared, with the “saintess“ always being put on a pedestal

Back to the MC knowing her best, the saintess shouldered a lot of expectations which she solely spoke of to the MC and they were BEST friends. The MC knew of her feelings that weren’t always positive about her burden as a noble, the male leads, and what not.

After the death, the MC is a little aimless. The male leads and parents then begin to seek her out since she was closest and they learn a little bit more about what was behind the saintess’ mask now that the MC no longer has to hide her secrets. The MC lashes out at one point about how her idolization caused the saintess distress. Even before that though: Bit by bit, those people start to approach the MC more and start treating her similarly to the saintess (better treatment, romantic interest in her) as they see similarities between the two and they realize the MC is the last or at least best/most genuine vestige they have of the deceased.

I remember there was at least one crown prince/high duke sort of character who was a love interest and extremely standoffish and disliked the MC due to her low status or dullness. Also I think there was a hot-headed male ginger(?) character and another love interest who approached her first. The hot-headed one also disliked her for her dullness and often “clinging” to the saintess, at least in his eyes. Though that perspective of the MC was extremely common.

I also think there was a running theme of lillies/other mourning flowers and the MC frequently sitting alone on benches: either with the ghost of the saintess or more frequently, having flashbacks. The flashbacks start with her missing her friend then comparing her own treatment before and after the death, and also comparing it to the saintess’ treatment.

I know it sounds a little trashy but it was better written then I explained here and the art was pretty good! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of any of the main characters? Also, can you tell us anything else about the plot or characters? This is a pretty terse description.

Comment: Sure, though I thought the premise was pretty unique! I’m a little sick but I remember a bit. Post will be edited!

Comment: After the death of the saintess, does the MC run away from her household and open a store while pretending to be a commoner, until a chance meeting with one of the MLs? This sounds like something I've read, but I'm pretty sure she wasn't a saintess. I didn't read enough of it to know if any of the other details match.

Comment: No but thanks!!

Comment: So not "The bad ending of an otome", then. Do you remember about when you read this? You mention that the deceased might have been a saintess; do you recall her doing anything particularly magical? Or any other fantasy aspects of this story? Was it a reincarnation/transmigration story?

Comment: I read it more than a year and a half ago! I mainly remember her being very revered like among the nobles and people, like the funeral was large and also her death emotionally affected the high-ranked noble characters a lot, which may have been why my mind went to saintess. I do remember distinctly it wasn’t reincarnation or regression as the MC didn’t see it coming or do anything to stop it. The story was very regular and linear in that way. I won’t rule out transmigration though because I don’t remember anything specifically regarding that